# Not able to install Bert Serving server. "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement bert-serving-server"

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp, conda, elmo

I'm trying to set up bert-as-service on my office machine and I keep getting the same error.

I have Python 3.6.8 :: Anaconda, Inc. and Tensorflow 1.10.0 on my Conda environment and Python 3.7.2 on my local machine(CMD)(Windows 10).

I dont have tensorflow on my local machine because I keep getting the same error which I get while trying to install bert-as-service.

1. Can I just install bert-as-service on Conda environment? If yes, could someone tell me how to resolve the problem below?
2. If not, how do I install tensorflow on my system and then bert-as-service?

Error1 - Not able to install bert-as-service in Conda despite having per-requisites:

[image: Error 1]

Error2 - Not able to install tensorflow on my local machine:

[image: Error 2]

Comment: Please copy-and-paste the output of those two images into code-blocks just below each of your "Error" lines. Code blocks are delimited by three backticks on lines before and after the code block while editing your question. We strongly prefer text to images.

Comment: @cronburg would you prefer that I delete the Output screenshots? I thought they might be helpful

Comment: We prefer text to images, you should copy-and paste the output in those two images into code-blocks as I stated. That way the error messages are searchable.

Comment: Possible solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56009691/1542000 The error doesn't actually have to do with "could not find a version", it's an SSL certificate error.